# Nokia MapImage Route REST API max. number of POIs

Tags: rest, here-api

We are using Route REST API and we experience problem when passing many POIs to HTTP request (parameters "poixN"). Our request has about 1000 POIs and some of them are truncated (hard to count, but definitely not all are shown). Here's an example request (first line is URL, the others are parameters passed with POST):

```
http://maps.nlp.nokia.com/mia/1.6/route?app_code=<APP_CODE>&app_id=<APP_ID>
h=440
w=1030
poix0=52.2420610745,21.0951604874;FFFFEA00;FFFFEA00;1;.
poix1=52.2420610745,21.0952168365;FFFFEA00;FFFFEA00;1;.
poix2=52.2420610745,21.0951024308;FFFFEA00;FFFFEA00;1;.
poix3=52.2047067699,20.9944339802;FFFFEA00;FFFFEA00;1;.
...
poix940=52.1749134848,20.9056261531;FFEE7AFF;FFEE7AFF;1;.
q=100
```

Is there a limit for number of POIs? What about other parameters like "r"?

We use enterprise version. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**

Ok, after some research I know the limit for "poixN" is 99. Any way to increase the limit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to increase the number of POIs available using the [Map Image API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image), but it would be possible to obtain a screenshot of a more complex map using the Enterprise [Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps) using the `ContextMenu.captureHandler`

You can add the [captureHandler](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics_api_nlp/nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu.html#topic-apiref__ContextMenu-zoomHandler-static-property) to a context menu as shown:

```
var contextMenu = new nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu();
  contextMenu.addHandler(nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu.captureHandler);
  map.components.add(contextMenu);
```

You can then obtain a screenshot with all your POIs, which could then be used for printing for example.The [HERE Maps Community on GitHub](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#map-tiles__hi-res-printable-map) hosts a working example specifically for printing which uses hi-res tiles from the [Map Tile API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/) as well. Note that screen capture **only works on the Firefox Browser**.

Since you have such a high number of POIs, I would also recommend looking at [clustering](https://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/data-visualization/custom-cluster-theme.html) to avoid overwhelming your users with too much information.